# Bulk convert from PNG/TIFF to JPG with minimal loss in quality

Tags: images, file-metadata, jpeg

I need to upload my photos to Shutterfly, but they don't seem to support EXIF data on PNG/BMP images. I need to thus convert to JPG for some prints, but I want to lose as little information as possible because the prints will be large format.

Is there any way to efficiently bulk convert PNG/TIFF images to JPG with a minimal loss in quality (using imagemagick or otherwise)? The relevant point is that they will print location/time on the print if included in the metadata. I would like to make use of that feature.

Comment: What is in the exif data that is relevant for your printer? I ask because that would be important to preserve.

Comment: Also, I don't see how the BMP file format would contain EXIF at all. So, this **very** much feels like an XY Problem, where you ask about a solution for X, but your problem is actually Y, which isn't solved by X; sadly, you forget to tell us about Y!

Comment: In part of your question you reference BMP format images. Later on you talk about TIFF. Do you mean one or both?

Comment: @MarcusMüller - I have (mostly) PNG and (some) TIFF images I want to upload to Shutterfly. Support said they support PNG and BMP but will drop EXIF data and JPG with EXIF data. Hence, my question about converting from PNG to JPG while keeping EXIF data with minimal quality loss

Comment: @roaima - please see above comment

Comment: @olivarb but what is it that *matters* about EXIF to a printer? I'm very confused which *problem* we're solving. Why do you want to send EXIF data to someone who puts images on paper?

Comment: @MarcusMüller They will print location/time on the print. I would like to make use of that feature

Comment: Ah, OK! Yeah that tells us what information to preserve, and how :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `imagemagick` you can set the quality of output images like this"

```
convert input_file.bmp -quality 90 output_file.jpg
```

Of course you can set quality to 95 (or even to 100) to check the result, but IMHO 90 is very good value (and balance between quality and size). If you want to do bulk conver you can use command:

```
mogrify -format jpeg -quality 90 *.bmp
```

Comment: This answer is right, but it can't preserve exif metadata, which isn't part of BMP.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, you can't preserve something which do not exist :)

Comment: yep :) exactly, hence my upvote :)

Comment: @RomeoNinov - I'm not so concerned about size as it goes immediately onto Shutterfly and will be deleted from my computer. Is 100 max quality?

Comment: @olivarb, yes, 100 is a maximum quality